unclear logarithms properties
I do not understand this mathematical step in Tong's notes on statistical mechanics on page 18. He is deriving the entropy of a two state system ($N_\uparrow, N_\downarrow$) of $N$ particles.
$S(E) = k_B[N\log N-N-N_\uparrow\log N_\uparrow+N_\uparrow-(N-N_\uparrow)\log (N-N_\uparrow)+(N-N_\uparrow)]\\
= -k_B[(N-N_\uparrow)\log(\frac{N-N_\uparrow}{N})+N_\uparrow\log(\frac{N_\uparrow}{N})]\\
=\dots $
Can someone explain it to me? How can you get the second line from the first line?
thank you
P.S. If I expand the second line I get the first. However I cannot derive the second line from the first. How can i derive it? $$(N-N_\uparrow)(\log(N-N_\uparrow)-\log N)+N_\uparrow(\log N_\uparrow-\log N)\\ =N\log(N-N_\uparrow)-N\log N-N_\uparrow \log(N-N_\uparrow)+N_\uparrow \log N + N_\uparrow\log N_\uparrow-N_\uparrow \log N\\ =N\log(N-N_\uparrow)-N\log N-N_\uparrow \log(N-N_\uparrow) + N_\uparrow\log N_\uparrow$$

Can you expand the second line to get the first line?

Find the polynomials $P_1(A,B,C,D,E)$ and $P_2(A,B,C,D,E)$ of total degree $\le 2$ such that $k_BP_1(N,N_\uparrow,\log N_\uparrow,\log(N-N_\uparrow),\log N)$ is the first expression and $k_BP_2(N,N_\uparrow,\log N_\uparrow,\log(N-N_\uparrow),\log N)$ is the second expression, and ascertain that $P_1=P_2$.

Just a little algebra... and you get there!

If I expand the second line I get the first. However I cannot derive the second line from the first. How can i derive it? $(N-N_\uparrow)(\log(N-N_\uparrow)-\log N)+N_\uparrow(\log N_\uparrow-\log N)\
=N\log(N-N_\uparrow)-N\log N-N_\uparrow \log(N-N_\uparrow)+N_\uparrow \log N + N_\uparrow\log N_\uparrow-N_\uparrow \log N\
=N\log(N-N_\uparrow)-N\log N-N_\uparrow \log(N-N_\uparrow) + N_\uparrow\log N_\uparrow\$

If you must convert $N_\uparrow \log N_\uparrow$ into $N_\uparrow \log \frac{N_\uparrow}{N}$, you must force a $-N_\uparrow \log N$ somehow.  One of the usual ways to force the appearance of a term is to insert a "fancy form of zero" using that term and its negation.  (Another is a "fancy form of one", usually when a factor is needed in a specific term.)

\begin{align*}
k_B[&N\log N - \underline{N}-N_\uparrow\log N_\uparrow+\underline{N_\uparrow} \\
&\qquad {}-(N-N_\uparrow)\log (N-N_\uparrow)+\underline{(N-N_\uparrow)}]  \\
&= k_B[N\log N -N_\uparrow\log N_\uparrow -(N-N_\uparrow)\log (N-N_\uparrow)]  \\
&= -k_B[-N\log N+N_\uparrow\log N_\uparrow+(N-N_\uparrow)\log (N-N_\uparrow)]  \\
&= -k_B[-N\log N+N_\uparrow\log N_\uparrow+(N_\uparrow\log N - N_\uparrow\log N) \\
&\qquad {}+(N-N_\uparrow)\log (N-N_\uparrow)]  \\
&= -k_B\left[-N\log N+N_\uparrow\log \frac{N_\uparrow}{N}+(N_\uparrow\log N ) \right.\\
&\qquad {}+(N-N_\uparrow)\log (N-N_\uparrow)]  \\
&= -k_B\left[(N_\uparrow-N)\log N+N_\uparrow\log \frac{N_\uparrow}{N} \right.\\
&\qquad {}+(N-N_\uparrow)\log (N-N_\uparrow)]  \\
&= -k_B\left[-(N-N_\uparrow)\log N+N_\uparrow\log \frac{N_\uparrow}{N} \right.\\
&\qquad {}+(N-N_\uparrow)\log (N-N_\uparrow)]  \\
&= -k_B\left[(N-N_\uparrow)\log\frac{N-N_\uparrow}{N}+N_\uparrow\log\frac{N_\uparrow}{N}\right]  \text{.}
\end{align*}

@user361410 : Comment to Question contains the answer to your Comment.

okay, now I've read it, thank you

$\require{cancel}$
$$N\log N\cancel{-N}-N_\uparrow\log N_\uparrow+\cancel{N_\uparrow}-(N-N_\uparrow)\log (N-N_\uparrow)+(\cancel N-\cancel{N_\uparrow})$$
$$=(N-N_\uparrow+N_\uparrow)\log N-N_\uparrow\log N_\uparrow-(N-N_\uparrow)\log (N-N_\uparrow)$$
$$=(N-N_\uparrow)[\log N-\log (N-N_\uparrow)]+N_\uparrow(\log N-\log N_\uparrow)$$
$$=-(N-N_\uparrow)\log\frac{N-N_\uparrow}N-N_\uparrow\log\frac{N_\uparrow}N.$$

My other answer is a "fancy form of zero" answer.  This is a "fancy form(s) of one" answer.  Sometimes one method is clearer than the other.
\begin{align*}
k_B[&N\log N - \underline{N}-N_\uparrow\log N_\uparrow+\underline{N_\uparrow} \\
&\qquad {}-(N-N_\uparrow)\log (N-N_\uparrow)+\underline{(N-N_\uparrow)}]  \\
&= k_B[N\log N -N_\uparrow\log N_\uparrow -(N-N_\uparrow)\log (N-N_\uparrow)]  \\
&= k_B \left[ N\log N -N_\uparrow\log \left(N_\uparrow \cdot \frac{N}{N} \right) \right. \\
 &\qquad \left.{}-(N-N_\uparrow)\log \left( (N-N_\uparrow) \cdot \frac{N}{N} \right)\right]  \\
&= k_B \left[ N\log N -N_\uparrow \left( \log \frac{N_\uparrow}{N} + \log N \right)\right. \\
 &\qquad \left.{}-(N-N_\uparrow) \left( \log \frac{N-N_\uparrow}{N} + \log N \right)\right]  \\
&= - k_B \left[ \underline{-N\log N} +N_\uparrow \log \frac{N_\uparrow}{N} + \underline{N_\uparrow \log N} \right. \\
 &\qquad \left.{}+(N-N_\uparrow) \log \frac{N-N_\uparrow}{N} + \underline{(N-N_\uparrow)\log N} \right]  \\
&= -k_B\left[(N-N_\uparrow)\log\frac{N-N_\uparrow}{N}+N_\uparrow\log\frac{N_\uparrow}{N}\right]  \text{.}
\end{align*}
